# Pull regular expressions from file and compare to each line in a file

Tags: regex, perl, eval, runtime-error

I found something that I could use on perlmonks.org (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=870806) but I can't get it to work.

I can read the file without issue and build an array.  Then, I'd like to compare each index of the array (each regex) to each line of a file, printing out the line before and the line after the matched line.

My code:

```
# List of regex's.  If this file doesn't exist, we can't continue
open ( $fh, "<", $DEF_FILE ) || die ("Can't open regex file: $DEF_FILE");
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    push (@bad_strings, $_);
}
close $fh || die "Cannot close regex file: $DEF_FILE: $!";

$file = '/tmp/mydirectory/myfile.txt';
eval { open ( $fh, "<", $file ); };
if ($@) {
      # If there was an error opening the file, just move on
      print "Error opening file: $file.\n";
} else {
      # If no error, process the file
      foreach $bad_string (@bad_strings) {
              $this_line = "";
              $do_next = 0;
              seek($fh, 0, 0); # move pointer to 0 each time through
              while(<$fh>) {
                      $last_line = $this_line;
                      $this_line = $_;
                      my $rege = eval "sub{ \$_[0] =~ $bad_string }"; # Real-time regex
                      if ($rege->( $this_line )) {                    # Line 82
                             print $last_line unless $do_next;
                             print $this_line;
                             $do_next = 1;
                      } else {
                             print $this_line if $do_next;
                             $last_line = "";
                             $do_next = 0;
                      }
              }
      }
}  # End "if error opening file" check
```

This was working before when I had just a string per line in the file and performed a simple test such as `if ($this_line =~ /$string_to_search_for/i )` but when I switched to regex in the file and a "real-time" eval statement, I now get `Can't use string ("") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at scrub_file.pl line 82` and line 82 is `if ($rege->($this_line)) {`.

Prior to that error message, I'm receiving: `Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at scrub_hhsysdump_file.pl line 82, <$fh>`  I have some understanding of that error message but can't seem to make the perl engine happy with my code thus far.

Still new to perl and always looking for pointers.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your input (`$DEF`) look like?

Comment: Also, `eval { open (...) }; if ($@) {...}` is a code smell. The `open` call might fail (and return `undef`), but it won't ever throw an exception. Some more conventional idioms are `open(...) or die "open failed: $!"` or `if (open(...)) { ...process filehandle... } else { ...handle error...}`.

Comment: Right now, it has only one regex - /fail/i

Comment: I'm not familiar with "code smells".  The purpose of this eval statement is to continue when an OPEN error occurs.  I am trying to `fornext` through an array of files and I'm having difficulty finding out why some fail with "Unable to open" errors.  I'll take your pointers into account.  I don't just want it to die, I'd like something that mimics a "on error resume next" or "try...catch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to see the reason for those `eval` statements - all they seem to do is make the code a lot more complicated and difficult to debug.

But `$rege` is undef because `eval "sub{ \$_[0] =~ $bad_string }"` isn't working, due to the string having a syntax error. I don't know what's in `$DEF_FILE`, but unless it has properly-delimited regular expressions then you need to add the delimiters in the `eval` string.

```
my $rege = eval "sub{ \$_[0] =~ /$bad_string/ }"
```

may work, but you may need `/\Q$bad_string/` instead if the strings in `$DEF_FILE` contain regex metacharacters and you want them to be treated as literal characters.

I suggest this version of your program which seems to do what you need without the fuss of the `eval` calls.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl ':seek';

my $DEF_FILE = 'myfile';

my @bad_strings = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $DEF_FILE or die qq(Can't open regex file "$DEF_FILE": $!);
  <$fh>;
};
chomp @bad_strings;

my $file = '/tmp/mydirectory/myfile.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq(Unable to open "$file" for input: $!);

for my $bad_string (@bad_strings) {

  my $regex = qr/$bad_string/;

  my ($last_line, $this_line, $do_next) = ('', '', 0);

  seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;

  while (<$fh>) {

    ($last_line, $this_line) = ($this_line, $_);

    if ($this_line =~ $regex) {
      print $last_line unless $do_next;
      print $this_line;
      $do_next = 1;
    }
    else {
      print $this_line if $do_next;
      $do_next = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good point about the metacharacters in my $DEF_FILE.  I'll keep that in mind down the road.  Right now, the $DEF_FILE has two lines.  If I put "error" (no quotes) on one line and "fail" on the next line and use your line above (with the delimiters), I get back matches as I'd expect (it works like it once did.)  However, when I move to putting regex in my $DEF_FILE, such as "/error/i" on one line and "/fail/i" on the next and remove your delimiters, then I get the same "strict refs" error referenced above.  Any ideas why it wouldn't like the delimiters in the file?

Comment: @harperville - does `$DEF_FILE` have any blank lines? That would be a problem.

Comment: @harperville: Because the delimiters are being put in twice. `sub{ \$_[0] =~ /$bad_string/ }` is expanded to `sub{ $_[0] =~ //error/i/ }`. If all you need to do is enable case-insensitivity then you can do it within the regex, like `(?i)error` and leave the delimiters out.

Comment: @harperville: You *really* need to drop the `eval` calls. They are confusing you and are unnecessary.

Comment: @mob, no blank lines.  @borodin, I'm not putting delimiters in twice.  if I put them in my code around the scalar, it works (`/$bad_strings/`).  If I remove them from my code and put them in my file, it doesn't work.  Thanks for the tip on (?i) and leaving delimiters out.  The eval isn't confusing me.  Taking it out presents me with an entirely different problem that I can't tackle right now.  With them in, I understand what is erroring.  It's part of a bigger piece of code that is irrelevant here.  I am making your code work now (isn't working) and will report back.  Thanks!

Comment: You should put  the  `eval` string into a variable so that you can print it before you eval it. Then you will see what is wrong with your syntax. The `eval` *is* confusing you. It is precisely where you are stuck.

Comment: Ah, you're referring to the eval in the $regex variable.  I thought you were referring to the eval around the open file call (line 10).

Comment: @harperville: Both evals are wrong, but you may as well leave the first one in place for now as long as it works.

Comment: I can't get anything to work now.  All I get is `[Fri Jan 11 11:29:34 2013] scrub_sysdump.pl: seek() on closed filehandle $fh at scrub_sysdump.pl line 71.
[Fri Jan 11 11:29:34 2013] scrub_sysdump.pl: readline() on closed filehandle $fh at scrub_sysdump.pl line 72.  And another problem has presented itself that I might need help on so I'll start another post.

Comment: @Borodin, I am back in action.  I am now where I was before with your code adjustments working.  Everything except me wanting to put the fill regex in my flat file.  I'm assigning my regex values to $regex but nothing is matching.  If I print out my $regex variable's value to the screen, I see:

    $regex=qr/fail/
    $regex=qr/error/

But nothing is matching.  I'm not sure how to put the delimiters in my file and get it work work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I realize the regex is being treated as a string and not an expression.  I need some real-time expression to be compiled from my entries in my flat file.  Still investigating, will report back if I make progress.

Comment: I'll just have to move forward with this.  I can put "(?i)error|fail" in my file and use your code `$regex=qr/($bad_string)/;` and it returns what I want.  I guess I need to brush up on how to increase the complexity of my regex's in the flat file.  Thanks for the help.